# Error 419 (unknown status) React-js Laravel8

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-hooks, laravel-8

I have front project with `react-js` and `laravel8` for back-end, when I put my js files into resources folder and run my project everything it's working, but when I run react-js out of the larvel pakage I got this error

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/userManagement/deleteCharity 419 (unknown status)
```

this is the request

```
const CSRF = await getCSRF();
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("charity_id", Number(id));
formData.append("_method", 'patch');
try {
    const response = await axios({
        method: "post",
        url: `${BaseURL}/userManagement/deleteCharity`,
        data: formData,
        headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data", "X-CSRF-TOKEN": CSRF.data },
  })
  console.log(response);
  console.log(response.data);
  resetAll()
  // console.log('reset====>', currentApp)
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

It's works fine in postman but
I don't know what is wrong

Comment: Anyhow `csrf` is missing your post method

Comment: @A.ANoman No, I logged the CSRF and it have token

Comment: My questios is: if you use Laravel how api rest, why don't uses the routes in api.php? All routes in web.php, will are verfited for csrf middleware. You error is cause csrf don't exists

Comment: @gaidyjg when I put my js file into laravel the `RTL`  style not working